# How to remove npm from file after install?

Tags: javascript, npm

I have **npm init** in my working file but there is a mistake that's why I want to remove npm from my working file. after that,  I want to init it again in my same working file from the beginning

Comment: Did you run `npm install`? If so, remove `node_modules` folder as well, otherwise remove `package.json` and run `npm init` again.

Comment: Just delete it :D

Comment: yes I did .. i know how to use npm but don't how to remove it from file after npm init once

Comment: `npm init` without an initializer simply creates a `package.json` file. Remove it and you've `uninit`ed npm

Comment: yes i delete everything but when i want to start it from beggining there is the main problem... when i try to npm init  after delete node_modules, package.json  than they suggest me old npm which is init before

Comment: What do you mean "they suggest me old npm which is init before"? Can you provide the error log?

Comment: `they suggest me old npm which is init before`, is it the name of the package? that is the folder name.

Comment: Aren't you using version control? If not, that's the problem.

Comment: no it not name of the package neither folder name

Comment: i am using vertion control